# Determine if a string is greater than another string

Tags: c#, string, integer

I have two strings

```
 string A = "1.0.0.0";
 string B = "1.0.0.1";
```

I need to evaluate somehow that B is greater than A (version wise) either converting those two strings to integers or decimals or something.

I tried the following

```
Decimal S = Convert.ToDecimal(A);
int S = Convert.ToInt32(A);
```

but keep getting the following error, "Input string was not in a correct format."

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you working specifically with IP addresses?

Comment: I'm working on versions, not IP addresses.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See the [Version Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx).

You're  able to do something like this:

```
Version a = new Version("1.0.0.0");
Version b = new Version("1.0.0.1");

if (b>a) //evaluates to true
    blah blah blah
```

I haven't personally tested this exact scenario, but the `Version` class allows you to use comparison operators like I've shown here.

Comment: Which will work, so long as the strings have at most 4 numeric parts ;)

Comment: llya is indeed correct, anything more than that and you'll probably have to custom code one of the `String.Split` solutions that others have suggested.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I'm sure the splitting of strings also works.

Answer (score 3):

If your string has at most 4 numeric parts (separated by `.`), you can use the [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class to get a strongly typed entity that corresponds to these strings. `Version` implements the different comparison operators (`==`, `>`, `<` etc...) in the expected manner, so you can find out which is greater:

```
var a = new Version(A);
var b = new Version(B);

if(a > b)
  // a is larger
else if (a < b)
  // b is larger
else
  // they are identical
```

If there are more than 4 parts, you will need to split each string to its numeric components, convert each one to a numeric equivalent and compare the two resulting collections.

Something like:

```
var aParts = A.Split('.');
var bParts = B.Split('.');

// assumes the string have the same number of parts
for(int i = 0; i < aParts.Length; i++)
{
  var currA = int.Parse(aParts[i]);
  var currB = int.Parse(bParts[i]);

  if(currA == currB)
    continue;

  if(currA > currB)
    // A is greater than B      
  else
    // B is greater than A
}
```

Comment: not my dv, but you should also compare the lengths.  Currently if A is longer than B your code throws.

Comment: @Servy - Yes. That's the purpose of the comment above the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at `System.Version` class.
If the strings are in this format or can be converted to a version.

Version have comparers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare version strings in .NET, then you can use the [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class.

```
Version version = new Version("1.0.0.0");
Version otherVersion = new Version(""1.0.0.1");
```

The class provides operators to check if a version is greater or lesser than another.

Answer (score 1):

Split on the ".". Then convert each part to an int. Starting from the left: if A's fragment is lower, then report that A is first. If B's fragment is lower, then report that B is first. Otherwise, move to the next fragment. If you're at the last fragment already, report that they are equal.

If your strings have at most four parts (like version numbers), then as others suggested it's easier to use the [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using VersionClass a fast approach would be something like this.

```
string A = "1.0.0.0";
string B = "1.0.0.1";

int versionA = Convert.ToInt32(A.Replace(".", string.Empty));
int versionB = Convert.ToInt32(B.Replace(".", string.Empty));

if (b>a)
//something will happen here
```

**Replace** changes the first string to the second one in this case string.Empty equals to "".

Comment: using the Version class *is* a fast approach, and it doesn't have the horrible bug that Mike just pointed out.